# Best posible circumference within an irregular polygon given by linear functions?

Tags: functions, linear-algebra, polygons

I would appreciate any formula or theory on how to calculate the radio of the best circumference within linear functions given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was this intended for Math.SE.com? It does not seem to be a question involving the software Mathematica per se.

Comment: Yes Daniel, Thanks.